# Best way to append name last modified timestamp of jar file to S3 bucket in gitlabci?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, aws-cli, gitlab-ci-runner

[image]

As shown in the image, in GITLAB CI I am unable to copy/rename a jar file with timestamp. However in local I am able to do it, see below.

aws s3 cp s3://app-jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar s3://app-jars/fallback-jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fallback-$LAST_MODIFIED.jar
copy: s3://app-jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to s3://app-jars/fallback-jars/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fallback-2024-02-19T01:24:27+00:00.jar

Any idea what might be the issue with timestamp in GitLab CI?

Comment: Put the filename in quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed it to -“$LAST_MODIFIED”